# npruntime example plugin (c++) of NPAPI fails to run on mac OSX 10.5

Tags: c++, macos, plugins, npapi, npruntime

I have compiled Mozilla NPAPI plugin example npruntime on Mac OSX 10.5.
It give me a libnprt.dylib

I am bundling this dylib with proper plist.

On loading the plugin, NP_GetMIMEDescription() is getting called (i am logging this), but its not going inside NP_GetEntryPoints().

How a part of code is getting loaded and a part not?

Can you suggest me of any other documentation or example code?
Any light on "How to make an NPAPI plugin for Mac"?

Advance thanks
-Parimal Das

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving your problem with the npruntime sample is a bit hard with the details given. I suggest checking out [WebKits](http://webkit.org/) examples from their repository. Mac-wise Mozillas samples are somewhat outdated.

To spare yourself from implementing it all, you can also take a look at:

- [QtBrowserPlugin](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/developingplugins.html)
- [FireBreath](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) (Cocoa support is work-in-progress though at the moment)

If you haven't found it already you might also find this [NPAPI plugin introduction](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/) helpful.

Comment: colonelpanic.net was indeed my starting point :)
The example code here (http://nativeclient.googlecode.com/svn-history/r168/trunk/nacl/googleclient/native_client/third_party/npapi_plugin/) is working correctly....though with some tweaks.

I was having build issues with FireBreadth, have to check with the latest.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you continue having build issues with FireBreath, join the google group and ask us about them!  We'll try to help you out.